# Setting up multiple network interfaces

Tags: networking, 14.04, maas

I'm trying to setup Ubuntu Cloud, while setting up MAAS I have a simple problem, I have 2 network interfaces, eth0 and eth1, eth0 is to connect the cluster to the internet through my router, and eth1 is to manage the cluster, after auto configuration of eth0 how would i go about adding eth1, having DHCP & DNS as well?

~Thanks

Comment: Or should i just reconfigure the network to my gigabyte ethernet card and let my router do the DHCP work? (Assuming using the routers default DHCP will allow PXE boot)

Answer (score 0):

When you installed MAAS it will automatically also set up a cluster controller interface. You will need to configure this to reflect the network you want. If you read the docs at http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/cluster-configuration.html this should outline what needs to be done.

[image: maas cluster controller settings]

In your case, two interfaces should be listed, and you should select eth1 to be managed with DHCP and DNS.

Comment: i tried that, but my other interface does not show up in ifconfig and the pxe boots not working, ill try again, also eth1 isnt shown by default only eth0, i manually added eth1 but it did no good.

Comment: I think i found the problem, here is part of the output for lshw http://pastebin.com/Vs8cXrXU

Comment: Yeah, the PXE boot requires the tftp server to be running, which runs from the cluster controller.
Hmm, it seems like your Realtek NIC is disabled.

Comment: Yes, and im still trying to find a way to enable mine sadly :(